# what happens in the background of hosting a rest webservice using wcf

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I was trying to understand what goes on in the background when I write the following piece of code to host a REST webservice in WCF:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHostFactory(),
                                       typeof(MyConcreteService)));
```

Also, the class definition is something like this:

```
public class MyConcreteService : IService
```

where IService defines the ServiceContract and OperationContract with WebGET etc

In setting up the routes, I never mention `IService` anywhere. How does the server find out what contracts to use ? Can someone spell out the secret that goes on in the background which makes the webservice work ?

Comment: There's not much I could gather in the web.config file. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/JYRnzGjr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WebServiceHostFactory` returns an instance of `WebServiceHost`. That class will see if the service class itself is decorated with `[ServiceContract]` - if so, it will use it as the contract type. Otherwise it will look for the interfaces implemented by the service class to see which ones are decorated with `[ServiceContract]`. If it finds only one (which is the case in your example), then it will be the one used as the contract type. If it finds 0 or more than 1, it should throw an exception.

Having the contract type, `WebServiceHost` will add an endpoint with that contract type, the appropriate binding (`WebHttpBinding`) and an empty relative address. It will also add the appropriate behavior for web endpoints (`WebHttpBehavior`). That's essentially it; it may do other things such as setting up a content type mapper if needed, etc, but the beauty of the WebServiceHost (and WebServiceHostFactory) class is that you don't need to know about it (in most of the cases).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It was of great help. Is there a doc or some resource you can point me to, where I can read more about this ?

Comment: You can look at the documentation for the class ServiceHostFactory and WebServiceHostFactory on MSDN, I think that's the "official" documentaiton for these. And I've got a blog post on service host factories at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/14/wcf-extensibility-servicehostfactory.aspx with detailed information about it.